# Receive duplicate message from Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

I'm using Spring + Redis, and following this document -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/redis.html

My web could get the message sent from the redis-cli, but it receives the same message twice, which is unexpected.

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And the configuration for beans

```
<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379"/>
    <!-- the default ConnectionFactory -->
    <redis:listener-container>
    <redis:listener ref="listener" method="handleMessage" topic="chat" />
    </redis:listener-container>

<bean id="listener" class="com.wisdom.common.queue.DefaultMessageDelegate"/>
```

The DefaultMessageDelegate.java

```
@Service
public class DefaultMessageDelegate implements MessageDelegate {


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(String message) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

When the web service started, I could see there're two clients subscribing the channel, and the handleMessage() receives two same messages then, but I only want one.

```
id=4 addr=127.0.0.1:49487 fd=8 name= age=8750 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
id=5 addr=127.0.0.1:49510 fd=9 name= age=8636 idle=222 flags=O db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=56 oll=0 omem=0 events=rw cmd=monitor
id=24 addr=127.0.0.1:51069 fd=6 name= age=228 idle=228 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
id=25 addr=127.0.0.1:51074 fd=7 name= age=222 idle=222 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
```

Is there any idea of how to solve this? Thanks!

==============

Updated the code I used to send out the message:

```
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(RedisSetting.MAX_IDLE);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(RedisSetting.MIN_IDLE);
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(RedisSetting.TEST_ON_BORROW);
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(RedisSetting.NUM_TESTS_PER_EVICTION_RUN);
    poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(RedisSetting.TIME_BETWEEN_EVICTION_RUNS_MILLIS);
    poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(RedisSetting.MAX_WAIT_MILLIS);



    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig,RedisSetting.ADDRESS, RedisSetting.PORT, 10000, RedisSetting.PASSWORD);

   ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    newFixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


                Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
                try {
                   jedis.publish("DATA", data);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                   jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);
                }


        }
    });
```

The constants:

```
public static final Integer MAX_IDLE = 5;

public static final Integer MIN_IDLE = 1;

public static final Boolean TEST_ON_BORROW = true;

public static final Integer NUM_TESTS_PER_EVICTION_RUN = 10;

public static final Integer TIME_BETWEEN_EVICTION_RUNS_MILLIS = 6000;

public static final Integer MAX_WAIT_MILLIS = 10000;
```

Comment: The XML config looks well. Looks like your `redisConnectionFactory`/the `listener-container` is registered twice. The `CLIENT LIST` output is another indicator for this behavior.

Comment: would you write down the code that publishing the message?